# How to remove disable attribute from button when user types all info in input and checked checkbox?

Tags: jquery

How to remove disable attribute from button when user types all info in input and checked checkbox?

My try:

FULL CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/7zMRM/1/

```
$('#id_accept').click(function(){
    if($('#id_accept:checked').length == 1 && $('#id_blz').length == 8 && $('#id_account_owner').length > 3 && $('#id_account_number').length == 22 && $('#id_bank_name').length > 3){

        $('#open').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#open').attr('onclick','javascript:yourFunctionName();');
    }
    else{
        $('#open').removeAttr('onclick');
        $('#open').attr('disabled','disabled');

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not do this on:

```
$('#id_accept').click(function(){
```

So, you need to do on the `input`'s `change` event.

```
$("form input").change(function(){
```

Moreover, you haven't wrapped the assignment inside `$(document).ready()` and also, you have two forms.

And also, you have to check for the checkbox value this way:

```
$('#id_accept').prop("checked");
```

Another mistake is you should not use `.length` that way, it should rather be:

```
$('#id_blz').val().length
```

#### Final Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form input').blur(function(){
    if($('#id_accept').prop("checked") && $('#id_blz').val().length == 8 && $('#id_account_owner').val().length > 3 && $('#id_account_number').val().length == 22 && $('#id_bank_name').val().length > 3){
        console.log("passed");
        alert($('#id_blz').length);
        $('#open').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#open').attr('onclick','javascript:yourFunctionName();');
    }
    else{
        console.log("failed");
        $('#open').removeAttr('onclick');
        $('#open').attr('disabled','disabled');

}
});
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zMRM/2/